# When I go to load my blog page, the base.html is extended and is working, but the content of my other html files are not showing. Why is this?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-urls

I have tried everything I can think of. I started off by going through the complete tutorial on Real Python. Now I am in the stage of building on it myself and have everything seemingly connected. All of the URLs and views and my database seem to be in order with no errors.

Whenever I go to the blog url, the base.html and navbar and everything are in place, but the actual content of my other html files are just gone.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load email_obfuscator %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  <! -- This line is to ensure proper rendering on mobile devices -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'projects:all_projects' %}">Portfolio</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'projects:all_projects' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"<a href="mailto:jordanmiracle@protonmail.com" target="_blank">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          More
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu"aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'blog:blog_index' %}">Blog</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other Stuff</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

blogindex.html

```
{% block page_content %}
(% load static %}

<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>Blog Index</h1>
    <hr>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <h2><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <small>
        {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
        Categories:&nbsp;
        {% for category in post.categories.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>&nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    </small>
    <p>{{ post.body | slice:":400" }}...</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock page_content %}
```

blogdetails.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <small>
        {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
        Categories:&nbsp;
        {% for category in post.categories.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog:blog_category' category.name %}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>&nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    </small>
    <p>{{ post.body | linebreaks }}</p>
    <h3>Leave a comment:</h3>
    <form action="/blog/{{ post.pk }}/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.author }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.body }}
        </div>
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h3>Comments:</h3>
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <p>
        On {{comment.created_on.date }}&nbsp;
        <b>{{ comment.author }}</b> wrote:
    </p>
    <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

blogcategories.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>{{ category | title }}</h1>
    <hr>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail' post.pk%}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <small>
            {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
            Categories:&nbsp;
            {% for category in post.categories.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'blog:blog_category' category.name %}">
                {{ category.name }}
            </a>&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
        </small>
        <p>{{ post.body | slice:":400" }}...</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
]
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post, Comment
from blog.forms import CommentForm


def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog/blog_index.html", context)


def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).order_by(
        '-created_on'
    )
    context = {
        "category": category,
        "posts": posts
    }
    return render(request, "blog/blog_category.html", context)


def blog_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()

    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', context)
```

Also, a chunk of my settings file that may be pertinent.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects/templates/projects'),
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3afV.png)

Does anybody know why this would be? I tried to post code but it was a mess. I'm only just now becoming active on here.

If anybody needs anymore information, or needs me to present any code I would be happy to do so. I will just screenshot everything I can. This has just been frustrating the hell out of me and I want to move on and get this one out of my head. Any help would be great.

Comment: Show your templates please?

Comment: I added some templates to the original. If you can't find anything there, I can post more. Also, I can show my file structure if necessary. Because I have been a little wary of that. I know I have it generally correct. But I just can't tell if something is off.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `{% extends "base.html" %}` in your blogindex.html (for the version that you pasted here)

The second thing: the blocks in your base.html are called `content` while you use it as `{% block page_content %}`

Comment: Oh crap, no I just looked to be sure, and (% extends "base.html" %} is in my original blogindex.html. That's the one line that I accidentally cropped out. Is there anything else obvious that you see or should I post some more files?